# Byte array Marshalling

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

My application is receiving a struct from another application via UDP socket. The other application is written in C++. The struct has variables of different types.
On my application side, I decode the received message from byte array to the desired type and put it in a Dictionary type variable `DecodedMessage` in the following way:

```
DecodedMessage.Add("VarName", (float)BitConvertor.ToInt32(Buffer, VarOffset));
```

Problem is that the values I get are not correct. I believe the problem is that I have to do some kind of Marshaling, but I have no idea how to do it.
The C++ application uses a #pragma pack(1) declaration.

Comment: Can you give an example of incorrect value? Like expected = x, got = y? It may be related to endianness if your c++ app uses big-endian encoding and c# code little-endian or vice versa

Comment: @DenisYarkovoy The numbers are just exploding. Instead of getting a value of about 1.02, I get 1E+09 or so.

Comment: well in your code you are reading Int32 from the buffer, so you can't expect to get 1.02. If you get floating point numbers in your c++ struct than the answer given by T_D is correct and you need to use ToSingle converter to read your float properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the C++ application is sending float values you need to use [BitConverter.ToSingle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of *ToInt32()*. But it is not clear from your question if this is the case or if the C++ app is sending int values that you just want to save as float value.

**EDIT**

Ok, your C++ app is sending a certain struct, let's assume it looks like this:

```
struct whatever
{
   int var1;
   float var2;
   byte var3[16];
}
```

Since you know the structure of the data, you can read it with a BinaryReader like this:

```
var binReader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(Buffer));
int var1 = binReader.ReadInt32();
float var2 = binReader.ReadSingle();
byte[] var3 = binReader.ReadBytes(16);
```

Now you can do whatever you want with that data.

Comment: The C++ sends a struct that has fields of different types (i.e. ints, floats, chars, longs). Also, I do want to save all data as floats. That said, do you think that the problem is with the BitConvertor?

Comment: @AnR, do not convert them, store them as they were received (`byte[]` ?) or somehow send their type and use `switch/case` to choose how to convert them (still, `VarName` should be `object` to be able to hold any type)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of marshalling, the UDP application can serialize the object and transfer the message through UDP socket. This is a modern mathod and supported by may C++ libraries (Example: serialization using boost library is very easy and fast to implement.